# Import a TXT file in an Excel spreadsheet to a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue where I would like to import a TXT file into Excel but need one section of the file to always be pasted within a certain cell, since all of the other code is based from that original cell location. I would like to modify my VBA code to be able to account for this flexibility.

Below is a picture that showcases the ideal scenario: the row highlighted in yellow is located within cell A47. All TXT files will be of a similar format and thus this row should always be pasted within this heading. The table that follows will then be put in the correct location for subsequent code.

[image: preferred format]

However, most of the time the TXT file will be of a different size, and thus that row will not be in A47. Below is an example of this:

[image: another txt file]

The part highlighted in beige is the one that changes depending on the text file size and thus is the source of the problem since it pushes the rest of the TXT file down. That beige section is not important though and so if that could somehow be removed/shortened to the correct size and the text below shifted to cell A47, that would be the goal here. This code needs to work for any size.

Here is the code that I have to import the txt file:

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
'Code to prompt the user to select a file (e.g. .TXT) and paste it in the Excel Worksheet

    Dim FiletoOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    
    'In place to prevent the popup warning dialog box about having too much information on the clipboard as well as screen updating
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Prompting and Opening file for user
    FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import")
    If FiletoOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FiletoOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AA1000").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
           
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File2()
'Code to prompt the user to select a file (e.g. .TXT) and paste it in the Excel Worksheet

    Dim FiletoOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim Target As Range, rngDB As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim r As Integer
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = Wb.Sheets("ImportTXT")

    'In place to prevent the popup warning dialog box about having too much information on the clipboard as well as screen updating
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Prompting and Opening file for user
    FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import")
    If FiletoOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FiletoOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:AA1000").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False

    End If

    Set Target = Ws.Range("a42")
    Set rngDB = Target.CurrentRegion
    r = rngDB.Rows.Count
    If r > 2 Then
        Set rngDB = Target(3).Resize(r - 2)
        rngDB.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```